# 2 classes on css in a row

Tags: html, css

very simple question but I couldnt find anything about that.

first of all thats the picture..[image]

I found an example code,

why does people write the class like:

```
.card .additional {

bla bla 
}
```

what is the difference between this and separtly

```
.card {
bla bla
}

.additional {
bla bla
}
```

I hope the question was clearly. I dont know how to funktion like this calls, that way i couldnt found anything in internet. Hope for an answer here ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.card .additional` will only apply styles to elements with class `additional` which are descendants of an element with class `card`:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="additional"></div> <!-- will have .card .additional styles applied -->
</div>
<div class="card"></div> <!-- will not have .card .additional styles applied -->
```

`.card` matches elements solely by their class `card`:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="additional"></div>
</div> <!-- will have .card styles applied -->
<div class="card"></div> <!-- will have .card styles applied -->
```

`.additional` matches elements solely by their class `additional`:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="additional"></div> <!-- will have .additional styles applied -->
</div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Those two are different altogether.

When you have a requirement to have a css properties to `.additional{...}` class which has `.card{...}` has it's parent only then you have to write below code.

> `.card .additional{background:red;}` mean highlight `.additional` class **ONLY** with `.card` as its parent.

Demo:

```css
.card .additional {
  background: red; /* applies to only child(additional) class */
}
```

```html
<div class="card">Card
  <div class="additional">additional-1</div>
  <div class="additional">additional-2</div>
</div>
```

Independent classes:

> You have a requirement where even though `card{...}` is parent to `additional{...}` but you still want to have independent css properties that is when you have to use below code.

`.card{...}` and  `.additional{....}` are independent classes.

```css
.card {
  background: red;
}

.additional {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">card
  <div class="additional">additional-1</div>
  <div class="additional">additional-2</div>
</div>
```